# I cant build holding cell kitchen or Canteen help!

Tags: prison-architect

[image]

Well, basically, I started the game, read the CEO's letter, got the grant and built the requirements for the holding cell, but it won't let me designate it. Why not?  Its happening for my canteen, too.

Comment: Is the image low res for everyone?

Comment: basically it isnt letting me desiginate the room as a holding cell.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see what exactly is going on.

Comment: i did upload it in 1920/1080p should i send it to you via email?

Comment: No. Did you just build walls or use the foundation tool?

Comment: Thx for the help i used the walls i didnt do foundation XD i did it now thx a lot :D

Answer (score 6):

They need to be indoors. You're going to need to build an actual building using the Foundation tool. Indoors is a requirement for many of the rooms, with only a few exceptions (Solitary, Storage, Yard, and Kennel, among them).